# How to read markdown text and style it to html?

Tags: php, html, web

For example, I write news content in markdown text and when I request via PHP, then PHP will read markdown text and convert to html. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do some searching and you can see examples of it. It depends on your markdown. You could use bbcode and use something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Can you provide any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [ParseDown](http://parsedown.org/) lib for PHP. I don't know a native way to do this without external library.

Follow the [instruction of the gitHub repository](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown) for the installation in your project (with composer or just include the file).

After that, it's quite easy to use.

for example, I got markdown README.md file to parse to html :

```
include('Parsedown.php');

$readme = file_get_contents('README.md');
$Parsedown = new Parsedown();

$html = $Parsedown->text($readme);
```

Hope it helps.